# Extend Object[] for generic type

Tags: java

I am trying to define a generic method which can print array of object type. I have written following code:

```java
class ArrayPrinter
{
    public <T extends Object[]> void printArray(T t) {
        for(Object o: t) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }  
}
public class javaGenerics {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayPrinter myArrayPrinter = new ArrayPrinter();
        Integer[] intArray = {1, 2, 3};
        String[] stringArray = {"Hello", "World"};
        myArrayPrinter.printArray(intArray);
        myArrayPrinter.printArray(stringArray); 
    }
}
```

But it is not working and is throwing following error:

```
javaGenerics.java:7: error: unexpected type
    public <T extends Object[]> void printArray(T t) {
                            ^
  required: class
  found:    Object[]
1 error
```

I can understand from error that I provide a class name. But I don't know what would be the class name for array of objects.

Comment: You should rather type `public <T extends Object> void printArray(T[] t)`. And `T` is pretty much useless here, you may just have to remove it and make the method take an `Object[] t` parameter.

Comment: public <T extends Object[]> void printArray(T t) {

should be

 public <T> void printArray(T[] t) {

Comment: an array is an object, but not a class. Cannot be extended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change printArray to

```
public <T extends Object> void printArray(T[] t) {
    for(Object o: t) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

That is let T extend Object rather than an Object array and make t an array of T.

Actually it is not necessary to extend Object at all since the type parameter is always a non-primitive type

```
public <T> void printArray(T[] t) {
    for(Object o: t) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working. However, is there no way, we can extend object arrays?

Comment: @foxtrot9 An array is not a class so it can't be extended. And the array is just a structure that holds data and it is the data itself that is relevant, you want to print (or handle) the content of the array so it's the content that need to fulfill your requirements

Comment: You don't need to explicitly state `extends Object`. Then again, you don't need the type variable at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
public <T>  void printArray(T[] t) {
        for (Object o : t) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
```

should be the right way.

Instead of

```
public <T extends Object[]> void printArray(T t) {
        for(Object o: t) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need generics here:

```
public void printArray(Object[] t) {
    for(Object o: t) {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

This will work fine, because Java arrays are covariant.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the other answers the following explanation.

Array is an Object, but it does not have a class, or type itself. You can extend a class, but not an array, or any other group of objects in java. No group of objects can have a determined class definition. **Array** is a way of reserving **N pointers in memory** for specifying references to **multiple objects** in case of objects, or **values** in case of primitives. Therefore **extend from Array** is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you were trying to make a method that accepts an array of any kind of object. In that case, you can use the following.

```
public <T> void printArray(T[] array) {
        for(T t: array) {
            System.out.println(t.toString());
        }
    }
```

In this case, because you aren't really using the type T for anything you can actually just do this:

```
    public  void printArray(Object[] array) {
        for(Object o: array) {
            System.out.println(o.toString());
        }
    }
```

If you really wanted to extend the array class itself, it turns out you just can't: https://www.quora.com/Why-cant-the-array-class-in-Java-be-extended